# error on uploading custom 3D gltf file using Three JS

Tags: three.js, gltf, parceljs

I have created a simple model. Also converted that into gltf/glb. That model is showing up on babylon and as well as on three js. But whenever I am trying to import into my html file, error is showing up like,

**"GLTFLoader.js:149 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"**

**Note that, I am using Parcel Bundler for bundling.**

```
const loader = new GLTFLoader();

loader.load("model.glb", function (gltf) {
  car = gltf.scene.children[0];
  car.scale.set(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
  scene.add(gltf.scene);
  animate();
});
```

loader instance is successfully loaded. But the load method is not working. Please help me out.

Comment: Likely a duplicate of https://discourse.threejs.org/t/gltfloader-with-an-instance-of-dracoloader-is-giving-error/19327 and https://discourse.threejs.org/t/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0/13810.

Comment: Thanks mate, It was the problem of http server. I'd use Apache then . That solved my problem. 

Answer (score 0):

Thanks mate, It was the problem of http server. I'd use Apache then . That solved my problem.